# Get 1 row only from MySQL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to take only 1 row from database with no loop when i call it.
this is my code on CodeIgniter

```
$row = $this->db->get_where('tr_supervision',array('EMP_ID_MEMBER' => $EMP_ID));
    
    echo $row['EMP_ID_LEADER'];
```

i dunno how but i get the error

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysqli_result as array

Filename: C:\laragon\www\onlineform\application\controllers\Reimbursement.php

Line Number: 96

Backtrace:

File: C:\laragon\www\onlineform\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case your use it like this:

```
$row = $this->db->where('EMP_ID_MEMBER',$EMP_ID)
         ->get('tr_supervision')
         ->row_array();

echo $row['EMP_ID_LEADER'];
```

Please read more about query results here:
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html?highlight=query%20results

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('EMP_ID_MEMBER',$EMP_ID)
         ->get('tr_supervision')
         ->row_array();
```

Comment: There's no point in adding the select with * when that is done by default.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it